# Can I use environmental variables in find-file?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'd like to use environmental variables in find-file command. Something like this:

`C-x C-f $ENV_VAR/foo.txt`

Does find-file have this functionality? What is the syntax?

Comment: It works exactly as you wrote it. Have you tried it?

Comment: I did, but since I launched Emacs from other shell it couldn't find my environmental variables. I'm ashamed of myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the environment variable isn't set in the Emacs process, then of course it won't work. Environment variables are inherited by child processes. Setting an environment variable in some other shell won't affect Emacs. You can put `(setenv "ENV_VAR" "value")` in your .emacs to set the variable in the Emacs process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Barmar said, it works as you say... as far as you are not using `ido` or similar.

Type <kbd>C-h k C-x C-f</kbd> to know if you are using any enhanced wrapper for `find-file`, like for instance `ido`.

If you are using `ido`, you can type <kbd>C-f</kbd> in the prompt to revert back temporarily to the old plain find-file prompt, where you can type for instance <kbd>$HO `<tab>`</kbd> (to complete to $HOME), then write something like <kbd>/.pro `<tab>`</kbd> to complete to $HOME/.profile, etc.

If you were using another, you should check the documentation because they probably have a fallback method to.

Comment: This was a very stupid mistake of mine - I launched Emacs from another shell and tried to use my environmental variables. Nevertheless, your answer led me to a bit deeper investigation and it is well written, therefore I accepted it. Thanks

Comment: This isn't entirely true.  You can use `ido` but you won't get completion on the variable names.  However `C-x C-f` `$windir/` on my Windows machine transforms to `c:/Windows`, `$home/` to `c:/users/username` but does not complete the trailing slash on the directory.